# Why Mapreduce with YARN stuck on CDH 5.3?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

Mapreduce with YARN fail to move ahead of 0% map and 0% reduce. I am using Cloudera CDH on google compute high memory instance(13 GM RAM). 8 GB free ram is available on the machine. Can you please help me to fix it?

```
sunny@hadoop-m:~$ hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.5.0-cdh5.3.0.jar  grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
14/12/24 00:13:53 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-m.c.sunny-hadoop-trial.internal/10.240.253.233:8032
14/12/24 00:13:53 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
14/12/24 00:13:54 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 5
14/12/24 00:13:54 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:5
14/12/24 00:13:54 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1419360146634_0001
14/12/24 00:13:54 INFO mapred.YARNRunner: Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
14/12/24 00:13:54 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1419360146634_0001
14/12/24 00:13:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://hadoop-m.c.sunny-hadoop-trial.internal:8088/proxy/application_1419360146634_0001/
14/12/24 00:13:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1419360146634_0001
```

**Resource Manager Output**
[image]
**Some more info about job**
[image]

yarn-site.xml: http://pastebin.mozilla.org/8113782
mapred-site.xml: http://pastebin.mozilla.org/8113813

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server 's IP got changed because of DHCP service. Client configuration for HDFS and YARN became stale. I needed to update client configuration, I did it with Cloudera manager and now cluster is running fine.

Comment: I'm trying to use Cloudera CDH on google compute, can I ask you what procedure did you use for deploy? Did you use Cloudera Manager to install the various instances like when deploying on EC2?I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Sure, I used cloudera maager. I learnt steps of doing so from here  http://shop.oreilly.com/product/110000753.do

Comment: ok so basically you replicated the instructions for deploying on Amazon Web Services? Did it go smoothly?May I ask you whether you used a standard image (and if so which one) or if you created a custom one? Thanks

Comment: I used ubuntu LTE image. While cluster setup installation process in cloudera manager make sure that you use the full DHCP name of the machines and not the IP. You can get the full DHCP name of the machine by running linux command "hostname -fqdn". You will also have to put this fqdn name and public ip mapping in your client machine's /etc/hosts file for smoother cloudera manager access ( Don't worry if you don't understand the last line, You will get it once you start using cm.)